# Unable to call a method defined inside an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have defined an object containing an array of objects and functions and called the methods as below:

```js
var Person = {

  people: [{
      name: "Max",
      age: 41,
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 25,

    },
    {
      name: "Doe",
      age: 67,

    },
  ],
  greeting: function() {
    return "Hello, my name is" + " " + this.name;
  }

};

function searchByName(namePerson) {

  var result = Person.people.find(Obj => Obj.name === namePerson);
  return result;
}

var max = searchByName('Max');
max.greeting();
```

Is something wrong with my function definition? On running  it says "greeting" is not a function.

Comment: what is in var max ?? an object of person class ??

Comment: Your `gretting` function is a member of the `Person` object not of the underlying `people`.

Comment: Your object doesn't make sense, why does a `Person` contain a bunch oh people?

Comment: is Person really a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your Person into an actual class that you could instantiate with `new Person()`

```js
//make the person class
function Person ( person ) {
  this.name = person.name;
  this.age = person.age;
}

//add the greeting method to the person class
Person.prototype.greeting = function () {
  return "Hello, my name is" + " " + this.name;
};

//build your people
var people = [
  new Person( { name: "Max", age: 41 } ),
  new Person( { name: "John", age: 25 } ),
  new Person( { name: "Doe", age: 67 } )
];

function searchByName(namePerson) {
  var result = people.find(person => person.name === namePerson);
  return result;
}

var max = searchByName('Max');
console.log( max.greeting() );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer , this seems to work .i am a beginner in javascript just trying out . i wanted variable array of objects and search function to be an external one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense, your `greeting` function is on the outer Person object but you are using it as if it were a property of each person inside the array.

You need a constructor for persons so you can instantiate three `Person`s with a `greeting` method

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
  return "Hello, my name is " + this.name + " and I am " + this.age +  " years old";
}


const people = [
    new Person("Max", 41),
    new Person("JOhn", 25),
    new Person("Doe", 67), 
];

function searchByName(namePerson) {
  var result = people.find(obj => obj.name === namePerson);
  return result;
}

var max = searchByName('Max');
console.log(max.greeting());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an object, which does not have a greeting function.

A potential different solution with a little bit of a different structure is this.

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
  return "Hello, my name is " + this.name;
}

function People(personArr) {
  this.people = personArr;
}

People.prototype.searchByName = function(name) {
  return this.people.find( person => person.name === name);
}

var people = new People([new Person("Max", 41), new Person("John", 25), new Person("Doe", 67)]);
var max = people.searchByName("Max");
console.log(max.greeting());
```